# WordPress BootStrap drop down navigation

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navigation

I am currently using WordPress, and this code to create my navigation:

```
    <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">
      <div id="main-nav">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
          'menu'              => 'header-menu',
          'theme_location'    => 'header-menu',
          'depth'             => 1,
          'container'         => 'div',
          'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
          'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
          'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
          'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
          'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
        );
        ?>
      </div>
```

This displays the menu 'header-menu', from the appearance - menu structure.

The issue is, I would like it to become a dropdown menu. When I am trying to drag in one of my custom post type categories, it brings up an error, as shown below.

[image: current menu]

I am wondering if there is a way, to get all categories inside this external products and display them in a drop down?

I do have a list of categories inside external products, which gathers all the categories and displays them with this code :

```
<?php foreach (get_terms('ExternalProducts') as $cat) : ?>
         <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'ExternalProducts'); ?>">
               <?php echo "<div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12' style='margin-bottom:20px;'>"; ?>
               <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 nopr"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" style="height:213px;"/></div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 categorytiletext">
                          <div class="testdiv">
                          <h5><?php echo $cat->name; ?></h5>
                          <p><?php echo $cat->description; ?></p>
                          </div>
                     </div>
               </div>



               <?php echo "</div>"; ?>
         </a>
```

Is there a way to just get the name of the page, and display this as dropdown on the navigation???

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? If so, could you share the solution. I am having the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I also still need to do this